# UIStackView, make it give up .spacing in compression resistance?

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout, uistackview

Say you have a vertical stack view, it has three items, and the spacing is set to **50**. It turns out to be 4 inches tall.

It turns out it's going to compress to about 3 inches (say, when the keyboard comes up - whatever).

You set CCRP to a low value - you indeed want the stack view to compress.

Oddly in all our experimentation, it seems that it ***will not*** collapse the "50" no matter what.

It seems that no matter what you do, it will take every other possible step, crushing the three items etc - but it will **never** give up the spacing.

- Am I in error?
- is there perhaps some separate way to set the CCRP "for the spacings" as such?
- Do you have to flag it somehow that you want it to give up spacings?

BTW I'm totally, completely familiar with the other approaches to do this. The question is how to make a UIStackView change it's mind about the spacings seemingly being immutable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct. The spacing doesn't change. You will want to add a spacer view to accomplish what you're looking for (the last paragraph of your post makes it sound like you're familiar with this approach).

Comment: Fascinating, it's great to know that's a fact, Connor!  Too much wine here to be certain.  I'm wondering, did you guys also figure that by trial, or is it actually mentioned somewhere in the doco - I could not find it.